# AngularJS controller object to directive in link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using angularjs, I am trying to populate a form dynamically and then submit the forms data via POST to a server.

I created a data variable in my controller (to POST later)

```
$scope.data = {};
```

Then

```
<div ng-repeat="(name, attributes) in fields">
    <element myvar="data" name="{{name}}" attributes="{{attributes}}" results="{{getValue(name)}}" ></element>
</div>
```

Where fields can look something like

```
{"agency":{"name_displayed":"Agency","size":"30","tag":"input","type":"text"},"department":{"name_displayed":"Department","size":"30","tag":"input","type":"text"},"description":{"cols":"50","name_displayed":"Description","rows":"4","tag":"textarea"}}
```

My directive looks like this

```
demoApp.directive("element", function($compile) {

    var template = function(name, attributes, results) {
        // returns template string
        // eg. returns '<input size="30" value="my agency" name="agency" ng-model="data.agency" type="text">'
    };

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var attributes = angular.fromJson(attrs.attributes);
            var tpl = template(attrs.name, attributes, attrs.results);
            element.html(tpl);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

For each new element, I would like to update the data object on the controller with the results attribute in order to populate the element.  I know how to do this using ng-model attribute if I am not setting the element's html directly.

Any thoughts?  Can I do this inside the link?

Comment: I would not set the directive name to *element*

Comment: create a demo in plunker or jsfiddle.net. Seems overcomplicated when you can simply populate `$scope.data` and use normal `ng-model` binding. Also don't understand why you don't use `template` option of directive